# Beautiful Binary String

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, strings, programming-challenge

Online challenge on [Hacker Rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/beautiful-binary-string).

> Alice has a binary string, `B`, of length `n`. She thinks a binary
>   string is beautiful if and only if it doesn't contain the substring
>   `010`.
>
> In one step, Alice can change a `0` to `1` a  (or vice-versa). Count
>   and print the minimum number of steps needed to make Alice see the
>   string as beautiful.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains an integer, `n` (the length of binary string
>   `B`).  The second line contains a single binary string, `B`, of length
>   `n`.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> Print the minimum number of steps needed to make the string beautiful.

```
public class Solution {
    private static int countChange(String text, String pattern) {
        int textLen = text.length();
        int patternLen = pattern.length();

        char[] chars = text.toCharArray();
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= textLen - patternLen; i++) {
          int j = 0;
          while (j < patternLen && chars[i+j] == pattern.charAt(j)) {
            j++;
          }
          if (j == patternLen) {
            count++;
            chars[i+2] = '1';
          }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        String B = in.next();
        System.out.println(countChange(B, "010"));
    }
}
```

Comment: The Java library has already done a lot of the work for you.  Why not use `String.indexOf(pattern, n)` to find the next occurrence of the pattern.  Change `n` to step along the binary string as each copy of the pattern is found.

Comment: Understand the intent of doing problems on hackerrank vs daily job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Generic pattern argument but hardcoded assumptions

It's nice that you added a generic pattern argument, but your code depends on the pattern being `"010"` here:

> ```
>       if (j == patternLen) {
>         count++;
>         chars[i+2] = '1';
>       }
> ```

Here, you have hardcoded both a `2` and a `'1'`.  Your program would crash if the pattern were shorter than 3 characters and if `i` were the last index of the array.  Also, if the pattern were `"101"`, setting the last character to `'1'` would not accomplish anything.

It would be better to just skip the rest of the pattern:

```
      if (j == patternLen) {
        count++;
        i += patternLen - 1;
      }
```

Comment: Nice idea, just remember that `i` would be incremented once more in the for loop.

Comment: @CodeYogi Thus `i += patternLen - 1` and not `i += patternLen`.